# Background Notification in Firebase: Android Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I tried to make notification in android 8. First there was a problem with defining notification channel. After that I got notification in android pre-Oreo and android Oreo just when application was running. I tried Job Scheduler and JobIntentService and also AsyncTask to make notification in android Oreo when application is not running but every time I got crash with below message.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=... (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{9078fd9 u0a148 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

What should I do for make notification in firebase background?

Comment: Are you building with Firebase version 10.2.1 or later?  10.2.1 is the first version that supports FCM for Oreo.

Comment: @BobSnyder I was using 10.0.1, now its work fine

Answer (score 2):

Use `JobIntentService` instead `IntentService`.

---

See also:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166636) in [FirebaseMessagingService Crashes on Android O due to background execution limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117554/firebasemessagingservice-crashes-on-android-o-due-to-background-execution-limits)