# ANR because of Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE in FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

**Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x11000010 pkg=in.swiggy.android cmp=in.swiggy.android/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }

com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver**

in Android 8 ND 8.1 devices

Stack trace from google play console:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73479f50 self=0x79546c0a00
  | sysTid=28427 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7959c449c8
  | state=S schedstat=( 364660644 78678379 421 ) utm=28 stm=8 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd16fd000-0x7fd16ff000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000007083c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
  #01  pc 0000000000020670  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+48)
  #02  pc 00000000000165a4  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+148)
  #03  pc 0000000000016484  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+116)
  #04  pc 000000000016053c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  #05  pc 00000000001efb8c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:325)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:142)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I am facing this problem after upgrading to Android Oreo. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: What version of firebase-messaging SDK are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseMessagingService Crashes on Android O due to background execution limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117554/firebasemessagingservice-crashes-on-android-o-due-to-background-execution-limits)

Comment: Would you like to share your finding on the same.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced these ANRs a lot too and the only fix that reduced it was this suggestion of updating the dependencies to 21.1.0 that removes the dependency on FirebaseInstanceId which is always part of these crash logs: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2014#issuecomment-820390156

So, updating these dependencies from

```
"com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.1.1”
"com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.2"
```

to

```
"com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0”
"com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0"
```

results in:
[image]

Hasn't completely gotten rid of it but I hope it helps some of you.