# Apps doesn't show any visible crash to user but still android vitals gives me crash reports of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-console

So, I have integrated FCM with version 9.6.1 all works fine but the problem is My android vitals showing crashes for every time user opens the app. But this crash is not visible to users neither it is being caught in log cat of android studio

Comment: You should add more information about the crash that android vitals is showing.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.seattleapplab.trymyui cmp=com.seattleapplab.trymyui/.Service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{26cc21 u0a174 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

Comment: @VedprakashWagh please refer the above comment

Comment: first update your fcm version

Comment: ok got your point but my question was why this same log is not showing in logcat of my android studio

Comment: if it shows then i can be sure that only library version is an issue not some other thing plus I want to make sure whether these crashes are background caught exceptions or user experience this crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the crash report that you've attached in your comment, I can see that you're using deprecated `FirebaseInstanceIDService`. Using that in your app will crash the app. In order to fix the error, follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Update your Firebase Libraries to the latest ones from `app/build.gradle`.
2. Change your `FirebaseInstanceIdService` to the latest `FirebaseMessagingService` and handle the notification handling in the `onMessageReceived` as well as other stuff in `onNewToken`
3. You can check out how to migrate from FirebaseInstanceIdService to the latest one from the following few articles.

• [FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated.](https://medium.com/android-school/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated-50651f17a148)

• [FirebaseMessagingService crashes on Android 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117554/firebasemessagingservice-crashes-on-android-o-due-to-background-execution-limits/48166636)

Comment: ok Thanks for your answer but one thing wanted to make sure whether these type of crashes making an app to force close it  or it is only logged in app quality

Comment: If it appears in Crashes section of Crashes and ANR that means your app completely Crashed. In the latest Android versions, it does not show that the app was crashed to avoid user frustration. You should fix the crash as soon as possible because it affects your app rankings in play store nowadays

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you find what you were looking for. The error in second link is pretty similar to yours.